# Ajax post returning empty $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Okay I think I am going mad because I have done this a million times before and now I can't make it work. I am doing an ajax post to a PHP script with some simple JSON and then returning the JSON from my PHP, however it is currently showing $_POST as an empty array.

Here is my js:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/account/book-promo.php",
  data: '{"firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones"}',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

And my PHP:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
exit;
```

Firebug shows that my request is using POST as it is supposed to and my data is being sent as JSON yet I am getting a response of:

```
array(0) {
}
```

The only thing I can think is that there is some kind of server settings that are preventing this from working, however I cant think why there would be. Maybe I have missed a bracket or something, it is driving me mad!

Any and all suggestions welcome!

Comment: Remove the quotes around the data : `data: { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones"},`. You might also want to add `dataType : 'json',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send it like if you want to send it as json.

```
data: { data : '{"firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones"}' },
```

and if you want to send it as `POST` just remove quotes `'`

```
data: {"firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones"},
```

Comment: you were just send a string with no key. not you are sending data with a key `data` in first case

Comment: okay that makes sense. I cant believe I didnt spot that! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json", // <---------------its required if response is json
  url: "/account/book-promo.php",
  data: {"firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones"}, //<---instead of string send the object this way
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

---

You said in your post *retuning the JSON from my PHP*:

so you need to use `dataType:"json"` and the data you are sending to your php should be sent as object (*which is usually to be pair of key and values separated by `:` like `{key:value}`*) as of your code you are sending a `string`.